# What sort of layout would I use for a custom day view calendar? (Android)

Tags: android, listview, calendar

I've read a lot of different questions on stackoverflow about custom day view calendars. Right now my project is using a listview to display all the events on one single day (e.g. Monday).

How would I implement the hours alongside with a listview while expanding the items proportional to their time duration?

I'm asking for the *layout(s) required* to do this, not the logic for sorting and assigning the items of the listview.

For instance, my goal is to get something similar to the Microsoft Day View:

[image]

Would I create a gridview instead and place the times on the leftmost grid? Then I should have the right column be filled to X dp based on the time?

Comment: i prefer to use tableLayout

Comment: Thanks! I will do some research on tableLayout and its hierarchical structure... One more clarification. I simply create an X amount of table rows (tablelayout's children) for the number of hours in a day (1-24) correct?

Comment: i think yes, give it a try